# Models for navigation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am looking for gazebo models which I can get to create navigation. ( so have to be compatible with rviz). I know that are Turtlebot, husky, dron, Pionner Models, but I want something less standard. Model have to have min 1 sensor which can detect obstacles.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329191/models-for-navigation/) by [aefka](https://answers.ros.org/users/33160/aefka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://answers.ros.org/question/12205/is-there-a-list-of-free-available-robot-models-for-gazebo/?answer=18021#post-id-18021

---

Originally posted by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) with karma: 308 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aefka](https://answers.ros.org/users/33160/aefka/) on 2019-07-24**:
I saw this, but I am looking for something different.